# Make the background of an image transparent in Pygame with convert_alpha

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make the background of an image transparent in a Pygame script. Now the background in my game is black, instead of transparent. I read somewhere else that I could use `convert_alpha`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is (the relevant part of) my code:

```
import PIL
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
img = pygame.image.load('snakehead1.bmp').convert_alpha(gameDisplay)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `convert_alpha` *adds* an alpha component to your image so you can make it transparent - but on its own, it does not. Where did you read this? Was there anything done afterwards?

Answer (score 9):

To make an image transparent you first need an image with alpha values. Be sure that it meets this criteria! I noticed that my images doesn't save the alpha values when saving as bmp. Apparently, [the bmp format do not have native transparency support](http://www.ehow.com/how_12224322_make-bmp-transparent.html).

**If it does contain alpha** you should be able to use the method `convert_alpha()` to return a Surface with per-pixel alpha. You don't need to pass anything to this method; if no arguments are given [the new surface will be optimized for blitting to the current display](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha).

Here's an example code demonstrating this:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
image = pygame.image.load("temp.png").convert_alpha()

while True:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    screen.blit(image, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

And my image (*"temp.png"*):

[image]

**If it doesn't contain alpha** there are two easy fixes.

1. Save the image with a different file format, like png.
2. Use colorkeys. This works if you only need to remove the background. It is as easy as putting the line of code `image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))`, which will make all black colors transparent.